# Why are the AI's vibrating when they are chasing/running each other

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
    //let meow=meowmeow
     let cell = []    
     let Xgrid = 200;
     let Ygrid = 150;
     let cpu = [];
     let CPUteam = 2;
     let AIdist = [];
     let Cpudist = [];
     let Cpudist2 = [];
     let lost = false;
     function setup() {
       smooth();
       frameRate(999)
       createCanvas(600, 450);
     }
    
     function draw() {
       Newcelltimer++;
       let cellDist = [];
       let cpuDist = [];
       if (lost) {
         background(0)
       } else {
         background(220);
    
         translate(200,150)
         scale(0.9)
         if (Newcelltimer == 1 ) {
           cpu.push(ceil(random(-Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)), ceil(random(-Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)), 20, CPUteam)
           OffSetX.push(ceil(random(0, 1000000)))
           OffSetY.push(ceil(random(1000000, 2000000)))
    
           cell.push(ceil(random(0 - Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)),
             ceil(random(0 - Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)))
           CPUteam++;
         }
           if (Newcelltimer == 0) {
           cpu.push(ceil(random(-Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)), ceil(random(-Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)), 20, CPUteam)
           OffSetX.push(ceil(random(0, 1000000)))
           OffSetY.push(ceil(random(1000000, 2000000)))
    
           cell.push(ceil(random(0 - Xgrid, 2 * Xgrid)),
             ceil(random(0 - Ygrid, 2 * Ygrid)))
           CPUteam++;
         }   
         
        
        for (let j = 0; j < (cpu.length / 4); j++) {
    
           if (cpu[j*4+2]>200) {
             lost = true;
           }
           
           let cpuDist = [];
    //Constrains the AI in the Canvas
--------------------------------------------
           if (cpu[j * 4] > (2 * Xgrid) - (cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2)) {
             cpu[j * 4] = (2 * Xgrid) - (cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2)
           }
    
           if (cpu[j * 4] < (-Xgrid) + (cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2)) {
             cpu[j * 4] = (-Xgrid) + (cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2);
           }
    
           if (cpu[j * 4 + 1] > (2 * Ygrid) - (cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2)) {
             cpu[j * 4 + 1] = (2 * Ygrid) - (cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2);
           }
    
           if (cpu[j * 4 + 1] < (-Ygrid) + (cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2)) {
             cpu[j * 4 + 1] = (-Ygrid) + (cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2)
           }
---------------------------------------------------------------------
           for (let m = 0; m < cpu.length / 4; m++) {
             if (m != j) {
               if (cpu[j * 4 + 3] % 2 != cpu[m * 4 + 3] % 2) {
                 distant = dist(cpu[m * 4], cpu[m * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1])
                 let higher = (cpu[m * 4 + 2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2]) ? cpu[m * 4 + 2] : cpu[j * 4 + 2];
    
                 if (higher/2 >= distant) {
                   if (cpu[m * 4 + 2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2]) {
                     cpu[m * 4 + 2] += cpu[j * 4 + 2]
                     cpu.splice(j * 4, 4)
                   } else if(cpu[j*4+2]>cpu[m*4+2]) {
                     cpu[j * 4 + 2] += cpu[m * 4 + 2]
                     cpu.splice(m * 4, 4)
                   } //Else
                 } //If
                 else {
                   cpuDist.push(distant);
                 } //Else
               } //If
             } //If
           } //For
           //Finds the Closest CPU's index value
    -------------------------------------------------
           let ClosestCpu = round(min(cpuDist));
           let ClosestCpupos;
    
           for (var q = 0; q < cpu.length / 4; q++) {
             if (ClosestCpu == round(int(dist(cpu[q * 4], cpu[q * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1])))) {
               ClosestCpupos = q;
               break;
             }
           }
   ---------------------------------------------------

    //Checks if AI ate a cell
    --------------------------------------------------
           for (let n = 0; n < cell.length / 2; n++) {
             let dis = int(dist(cell[n * 2], cell[n * 2 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]))
             if (dis <= cpu[j * 4 + 2] / 2) {
               cpu[j * 4 + 2] += 5;
               cell.splice(n * 2, 2)
             } else {
    //If cell is NOT eaten, pushes the distance between AI and cell into an array
               cellDist.push(dis)
             }
           }
        --------------------------------------------------

    //Find the closest Cell's index value
    -------------------------------------
           let ClosestCell = min(cellDist);
           let ClosestCellpos;
           for (let r = 0; r < cell.length / 2; r++) {
             if (ClosestCell == int(dist(cell[r * 2], cell[r * 2 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]))) {
               ClosestCellpos = r;
               break;
             }
           }
        --------------------------------------
           
Checks if the closest AI is close enough to either chase or run away from it.
    -------------------------------------

      if (Cpudist[j]) {
      Cpudist[j] = dist(cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4], cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 1], cpu[j*4], cpu[j*4+1]) < 250 &&  cpu[ClosestCpupos*4+2] < cpu[j * 4 + 2];
    } else {
      Cpudist[j] = dist(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[ClosestCpupos*4],cpu[ClosestCpupos*4+1]) < 200 && cpu[ClosestCpupos*4+2] < cpu[j * 4 + 2];
    }     
             if (Cpudist2[j]) {
      Cpudist2[j] = dist(cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4], cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 1], cpu[j*4], cpu[j*4+1]) < 250 &&  cpu[ClosestCpupos*4+2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2];
    } else {
      Cpudist2[j] = dist(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[ClosestCpupos*4],cpu[ClosestCpupos*4+1]) < 200 && cpu[ClosestCpupos*4+2] > cpu[j * 4 + 2];
    }  
    -------------------------------------

  let amp = round((cpu[j * 4 + 2] / Math.pow(cpu[j * 4 + 2], 1.44)) * 20000) / 2000;                        
  

//Moves the AI in the following way: If the closest AI is less than an arbitrary 250 then you run, if not, check if the closest cell is less than another arbitrary 250, then you chase the cell. Otherways, you use noise values to move (I deleted that because it was quite repetitive) 
     if (Cpudist2[j]) {
       //Run        
       
          let distXpos = cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4] - cpu[j * 4];
          let distYpos = cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 1] - cpu[j * 4 + 1];
    
             let higherVal = (abs(distXpos) > abs(distYpos)) ? distXpos : distYpos;
             
             let MultVal = 250/abs(higherVal);
             
             distXpos*=MultVal;
             distYpos*=MultVal;
             
             distXpos = map(distXpos, -250, 250, -1, 1);
             distYpos = map(distYpos, -250, 250, -1, 1);
             cpu[j * 4] -= distXpos * amp;
             cpu[j * 4 + 1] -= distYpos * amp;
           } else if (dist(cpu[ClosestCpupos*4],cpu[ClosestCpupos*4+1],cpu[j*4],cpu[j*4+1])<250&&cpu[ClosestCpupos*4+2]<cpu[j*4+2]) {
             //Chase
             let distXpos = cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4] - cpu[j * 4];
             let distYpos = cpu[ClosestCpupos * 4 + 1] - cpu[j * 4 + 1];
    
             let higherVal = (abs(distXpos) > abs(distYpos)) ? distXpos : distYpos;
             
             let MultVal = 250/abs(higherVal);
             
             distXpos*=MultVal;
             distYpos*=MultVal;
             
             distXpos = map(distXpos, -250, 250, -1, 1);
             distYpos = map(distYpos, -250, 250, -1, 1);
             cpu[j * 4] += distXpos * amp;
             cpu[j * 4 + 1] += distYpos * amp;
           } else if (dist(cell[ClosestCellpos * 2], cell[ClosestCellpos * 2 + 1], cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1]) < 250) {
             
             let distXpos = cell[ClosestCellpos * 2] - cpu[j * 4];
             let distYpos = cell[ClosestCellpos * 2 + 1] - cpu[j * 4 + 1];
    
             let higherVal = (abs(distXpos) > abs(distYpos)) ? distXpos : distYpos;
             
             let MultVal = 250/abs(higherVal);
             
             distXpos*=MultVal;
             distYpos*=MultVal;
    
             distXpos = map(distXpos, -250, 250, -1, 1);
             distYpos = map(distYpos, -250, 250, -1, 1);
             cpu[j * 4] += distXpos * amp;
             cpu[j * 4 + 1] += distYpos * amp;
           }
           if (cpu[j * 4 + 3] % 2 == 0) {
             fill(0, 0, 255)
             circle(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4 + 2]);
           } else {
             fill(255, 0, 0)
             circle(cpu[j * 4], cpu[j * 4 + 1], cpu[j * 4 + 2])
           }
         }
       }
Displays the cells on the canvas
       for (let k = 0; k < cell.length / 2; k++) {
    
         fill(0, 255, 255, 100)
         circle(cell[k * 2], cell[k * 2 + 1], 7)
       }
     }
```

Just wanted to mention this is made for debugging purposes in the AI's, for my OTHER program and my OTHER program is based somewhat on [agar.io](https://agar.io/).

- https://editor.p5js.org/Meowmeow/sketches/bJiOlWTkd The full program, with nothing deleted
- When the AI chases the AI, only then it vibrates, but it kind of chases it.
- The problem is probably in the CPU for loop
- The array is confusing, and should probably be a 2d array, but to try to explain it: The 1d array is in "Groups" of 4's, the first number is the X pos, the second is 2 Y pos, third is size, fourth is Team blue or Team red (If the 4th value %2 is 0, it's blue, else it's 1). So an array of CPUs could look like `[100,150,25,3,250,600,15,4]` then you would do a for loop, starting at 0, going to the length/4, then you draw the AI's, first AI would be at 100,150, size 25, Team Blue. the second AI would be at 200,600, size 26, team Red
- The cpuDist checks if you chase the AI, and cpuDist2 checks if you run away from the AI using oscillation. CPU comes within 200 of the player, and then sets it back to false when it gets to be 250 away. That way, it won't oscillate because it needs to move 50 pixels in order to change behavior. I think the problem is in this logic.

Comment: Your code is far from runnable (missing comment openers, missing variable declarations, ...), and very hard to read. 1. Break it into small functions. 2. Use javascript objects instead of silly array index assignments. 3. Your problem is probably due to rapidly changing speed / direction. Simulate acceleration or make a speed law that depends on all surrounding AIs with smooth functions

Comment: Ideas for you: https://youtu.be/JXuxYMGe4KI

Comment: Last one, more about attraction/repulsion laws: https://youtu.be/OAcXnzRNiCY

Comment: I put the full code in the first bullet point.

Comment: Well, people certainly won't spend 2 hours squinting through it to debug it for you. Moreover, you *yourself* would benefit from refactoring it in a more readable way. If you want quick and effective help, provide a minimal runnable example

Answer (score 1):

You should *reeeally* use objects. Your example array of two cpus would be something like this:

```
cpu = [
  {
    x: 100,
    y: 150,
    size: 25,
    team: 3
  },
  {
    x: 250,
    y: 600,
    size: 15,
    team: 4
  }
]
```

Then you can cycle through `cpu` simply by ones, and access the properties of each cpu something like this:

```
for (let ai of cpu) {
  circle(ai.x, ai.y, ai.size)
}
```

This wouldn't be too difficult to implement, just use find and replace.

For your actual question, I can't run your code as [julien.giband](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3410989/julien-giband) said in their comment. However, I believe the problem lies in the fact that you're only running away from the single closest CPU. Similarly to your previous question, the vibration is a result of changing behavior too quickly.

To illustrate this, suppose you have 3 CPUs in one dimension. Set their positions to 0, 49, and 100. Let the middle one have size 10 and the outer ones have size 20. I'm just going to suppose that the smaller one moves 3 pixels per frame and the bigger ones move 1 pixel per frame. Here is how they progress:

1. (0, 49, 100)

   - 49 away from left, 51 away from right, move right
2. (1, 52, 99)

   - 51 away from left, 47 away from right, move left
3. (2, 49, 98)

   - 47 away from left, 49 away from right, move right
4. (3, 52, 97)

   - 49 away from left, 45 away from right, move left
5. (4, 49, 96)

   - 45 away from left, 47 away from right, move right
6. (5, 52, 95)

   - and so on, you get the idea

You see how the middle one vibrates? That's what's happening in your code. If you want to fix this problem, you can do one of the suggestions that [julien.giband](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3410989/julien-giband) suggested.

If you want to run away from multiple CPUs, I recommend giving each CPU a list of the CPUs that are chasing it. I'm not going to try to solve it using your array format, but here is what a CPU might look like as an object:

```
single_cpu = {
  x: 100,
  y: 150,
  size: 25,
  team: 3,
  chased_by: [1, 2]
}
```

You can dynamically change the `chased_by` list similarly to how you change `Cpudist[j]` in your current version. It might look something like this (inside of the `j` loop):

```
for (let i; i < cpu.length; i++) {
  chase_index = cpu[j].chased_by.indexOf(i);
  if (chase_index == -1) { // if i is not in the list of cpus currently chasing j
    if (dist(cpu[i].x, cpu[i].y, cpu[j].x, cpu[j].y) < 200 &&
        cpu[i].team %2 != cpu[j].team %2 &&
        cpu[i].size > cpu[j].size) { // if i is bigger, on the other team, and within 200 of j
      cpu[j].chased_by.push(i); // add i to the list of cpus currently chasing j
    }
  } else { // if i is in the list
    if (dist(cpu[i].x, cpu[i].y, cpu[j].x, cpu[j].y) > 250 || 
        cpu[i].size < cpu[j].size) { // if i is smaller than or more than 250 away from j
      cpu[j].chased_by.splice(chase_index, 1); // remove i from the list
    }
  }
}
```

Then when you're calculating how to run away, you run away from the average positions of all the CPUs that you're running away from. You will have to do additional stuff in order to run away from the player and multiple CPUs simultaneously.